# problem npm run watch blocked in watching files

Tags: vue.js, laravel-6

---

```
   Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://192.168.0.106:3000
```

---

```
      UI: http://localhost:3001
```

UI External: http://localhost:3001

---

[Browsersync] Watching files...

Comment: Please add more details to explain exact problem you encounter.

Comment: i am using Vuejs and laravel 6 (laravel mix) in weather app the problem is in localhost:3000 they don't give me the laravel view (welcome.blade.php)